# Find a specific pattern in C and reading number that comes after the pattern

Tags: c

search the site but did not find this kind of question
i have a short txt file (Ini)
in it there will be config in this kind of pattern

```
blabla= 1111
kaka= 2313
blublu = 1
```

the problem in the way i wrote the code it find the pattern only if it in the first line

i tried this

```
int number;
FILE *Config;
char ch_theconfig[1000];

Config = fopen("config.ini","r");
size_t sizeofConfig = fread(ch_theconfig, 1, 1000, Config);

sscan(ch_theconfig,"kaka= %d",&number);
```

how do it make it look even after a new line?
thX for the help!!

****edit
is there no way to find pattern in full file without checking line by line?
or is there a way to make it to a new string who will be without the \n from the origenal file?

again thx

Comment: is there no way to find pattern in full file without checking line by line?
or is there a way to make it to a new string who will be without the \n from the origenal file?

again thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
    int number;
    FILE *Config;
    char ch_theconfig[0x1000], *p;

    Config = fopen("data.txt","r");
    size_t sizeofConfig = fread(ch_theconfig, sizeof ch_theconfig, 1, Config);

    if(p=strstr(ch_theconfig, "kaka=")){//"kaka ="?
        sscanf(p + 5,"%d", &number);//5 : strlen("kaka="),
        printf("kaka=%d\n", number);
    }
    fclose(Config);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @user3678933 strstr(const char *cstring, const char *search_cstring) : argument 1 isn't FILE POINTER.

Answer (score 0):

1.Use fscanf() in a while loop until the EOF character is detected.

2.Else if you want to read line by line use this

```
while ((read = getline(&line, &len, Config)) != -1) {
           printf("length %zu :\n", read);
           printf("%s", line);
       }
```

PS I haven't declared the variables but they are self explanatory

3 Or use fgets() as follows

```
while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, Config ) != NULL ) /* read a line */
              {
                 fputs ( line, stdout ); /* write the line */
              }
```

Comment: Isn't getline a c++ function ?

Answer (score 0):

Newline is also a character in file so you need to read and discard it to proceed to the next input in file. you can read it as character `%c` into some variable.